# BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition - microSD not recognised fully by the phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I still see that the phone has 3.8GB storage free instead of (3.8GB + microSD).
In External Drives I only see a circle going round and round and round.
I believe that the microSD mulfunctions.

Any possible solutions?

***Note: Samsung EVO microSDHC UHS-I Card Class10 32GB***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 32gb SD card in my bq E4.5.
But on the memory page you can only see the *internal* memory of the phone.
I can also see the default folders on my memory card.

If all these things are working on your phone as shown here you have no problem and everything works as intended.

If you want to know the size of your SD card you can open your terminal (needs to be installed first) and enter the command

```
df -h
```

and look for something like this (there will be multiple lines like this. the correct one is the one starting with /media/phablet)

```
/dev/mmcblk1                                  30G  8.6G   22G  29% /media/phablet/3930-C75E
```

This shows the size of the SD card (30G) and how much is used (8.6G) and how much is free (22G).

This screenshots are taken from my phone.

Memory page showing only the internal memory:
[image]

File manager showing that I have an SD card in my phone:
[image]

File manager showing the contents of the SD card.
[image]

df -h output
[image]

Comment: Ok Christopher thank you, but the internal memory has only 3.8GB free and the only thing that I have is only applications, is there an easy way to transfer the data to the sd?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with data. Images, movies etc can easily be placed in the corresponding folder on the SD card and will be found by i.E. the Music app. If you want to know how to transfer apps then I have to say sorry, don't know that. If this is what you want to know you could ask a new question how one can transfer apps to the SD card. Maybe someone knows. But to be honest I doubt that it is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Install and try with file manager app. To open select the storage swiping up. You will be asked for your password.

Comment: If you mean to open the sd from the file manager, this is working without a password. Is there a way to see that the sd is recognised and how much space there is in it? Everybody that has an Ubuntu Aquaris phone like me the only thing that they see is the internal 8GB?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the preformatted empty sd-card (endless turning ubuntu logo); my solution: completely removed the partition of the sd-card (there were 4MB free memory before the vfat-partition) with gparted on my desktop-pc; put it back in and let ubuntu phone format the sd-card;

now there is no free memory before the newly created vfat-partition and the sd-card works ;-)